# How to force Action Center to display on taskbar when it's turned on, but doesn't display on taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar, default-settings, action-center

I'm trying to open my Action Center, but this is what it looks like:

[image: Action Center not on Taskbar]

I looked through Settings and it's turned on, but I can't turn it off, which is ironic, since it doesn't display on the taskbar.

[image: Action Center turned on, but grayed out]

Can I force it to show on the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

If it appears greyed out like on your screenshot, it means it is disabled in the group policy editor. You can only change this if you have administrator rights.

Citing from [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/244539/how-to-disable-the-action-center-in-windows-10/)

> In Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, hit Start, type gpedit.msc, and hit Enter. In the Local Group Policy Editor, in the left-hand pane, drill down to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar. On the right, find the “Remove Notifications and Action Center” item and double-click it.

On the 'Remove notification and action center' screen, set to 'disabled'. That's it.